# Ender 3 V2 Neo upgraded with Biqu H2 V2 not extruding

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, extruder

I'm doing something special with my Ender 3 V2 Neo these days. Gotten to upgrade to the direct extruder Biqu H2 V2. Nothing is out for the Neo version yet - like adapters and such - so I have modified an Ender 3 Pro mount to make things work.

Everything is now mounted and looks awesome. But, the new extruder won't extrude. I have set the Vrefs to around 1.05 V. The E-steps are set to 932 using Pronterface. I am using Marlin firmware.

My mainboard is marked with T8 and it is using the TMC2208 driver. I have checked my stepper cable and there is good connection with the main board.

I took out my stepper motor cable from the Biqu and tried with the stepper motor cable from my X-axis, and then the Biqu finally started extruding when I adjusted the X value.

So I'm kind of puzzled of this issue?!

Is my mainboard toasted? Or could the E-stepper driver be possibly dead?

Anyone with good ideas?

After a good question on if i had worked on the board with the power ON i went into myself and thought; damn, i actually just have done that. And by trying to move the x-axis with the steppermotor just to have NOTHING happen... i think my steppermotor driver is dead by my own doing... I will buy a new one and let you guys know!!

Comment: Well @0scar mentioned something here, I actually did move my stepper cables when the board was powered. I didn't really think about it when I did...
So, when trying to move the X-axis now with the stepper motor, nothing happened... I actually think the stepper motor driver is dead because I didn't follow the right instructions of having the board off when moving wires. Damn I feel stupid :-(

My nozzle is 220 °C just to be sure, but good that you addressed this as well. I will buy a new main board then and will update here if I get it to work :-)

Comment: However, you said that the extruder also wasn't working ***before*** you moved the wires about (and that was the reason why you moved the wires in the first place). So, either there is another (original) problem.. or you had initially plugged in the extruder - after upgrading to the new extruder - when the board was switched on... do you see what I mean..? What was the original reason for the extruder not working? We still haven't really found a reason for that...

Comment: In addition, @EirikJohannessendusty_outdoo, your last update to your question seems to be an answer, or response to 0scar's answer, and as such it should have probably been posted as an answer and not as an update to the question, because that has meant that you've ended up answering your question within the question, which sort of breaks the Q&A mechanism of Stack Exchange. Of course, the whole Q&A has been complicated by the original issue apparently not yet having been fixed - which is: *why didn't it work in the first place?* Unless it was also due to cables being moved whilst powered up.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to continue through the process of elimination. You have proved that your x-axis driver works, by connecting it to the extruder stepper motor. Now you need to prove that your extruder driver works.

I would suggest to test whether your extruder driver is at fault or damaged, by connecting the x-axis stepper to the extruder driver and then trying to move the x-axis, in much the same way as you did with your extruder stepper motor connected to the x-axis stepper driver.

Whilst this isn't an actual solution to your issue, at least this way you can hopefully narrow down precisely where your issue is.

Answer (score 2):

Although not the answer, but more a step into solving the issue, when you swap cables, always un-power the board, never hot-swap cables as this can destroy the drivers. You could possibly be dealing with a dead driver.

You proved by swapping the X-axis for the extruder that the extruder works on the X-axis driver (now you now that the extruder stepper works), so you either did something wrong in your config file or the driver is dead.

You could look into what differences you have configured with respect to [the Marlin config for the Ender 3 V2 Neo](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/blob/import-2.1.x/config/examples/Creality/Ender-3%20V2%20Neo/Configuration.h) to look for possible problems with your config file.

---

*Furthermore, in order to extrude, your nozzle need to be at least 170 °C, else it will not extrude.*